# Get keys that are also in the value in defaultdict

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict

I am trying to extract keys that are also currently present in the values within a defaultdict.

For example,

`a = {1: [1,3,5], 2: [1,3], 3: [3], 4:[5]}` should give `1` and `3` since those values were in the value - i.e. `1` was in `1,3,5`

I wrote this code, but it isn't printing the duplicate key:

```
c = set():
for k, v in a.items():
if a[k] == v
c.add(k)
```

But it doesn't work, I think because it doesn't compare EACH individual item in the list, i.e. `1: [1,3,5]`

How to fix?

Comment: Can you please edit your code so that it runs? With the current syntax and the spacing/blocks, the code is not runnable. Anyways, to check if a key is *in* the values, then simply use the `in` operator. `if k in v` (if the key is present in the values).

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there; you just need to modify your condition a bit:

```
a = {1: [1,3,5], 2: [1,3], 3: [3], 4:[5]}
c = set()
for k, v in a.items():
    if k in v:
        c.add(k)
```

This can be simplified to a set comprehension:

```
a = {1: [1,3,5], 2: [1,3], 3: [3], 4:[5]}
c = {k for k, v in a.items() if k in v}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested set comprehension that iterates over the sub-lists in the dict values and outputs the list items that are keys of the dict:

```
{k for l in a.values() for k in l if k in a}
```

This returns:

```
{1, 3}
```